# How to detect the key follow by a value with a specific character and remove it from the string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a question related to regex pattern as I have a string as below:

```
s = """[{"id" : 645042","begin": 33,"end": 46,"entity": "New York City","text": "New York City","score": 0.40,"categories" : ["New York City","Cities in New York","Former capitals of the United States","Former United States state capitals","Government of New York City","Metropolitan areas of New York","Populated places established in 1624","Populated places on the Hudson River","Port cities and towns of the United States Atlantic coast","1624 establishments in the Thirteen Colonies","Article Feedback 5 Additional Articles"]}]"""
```

Actually here I need to detect maybe the value in the key "id" and remove the " from 645042.

Actually, I have try this:

```
s = re.sub(r'([0-9]+)\"','\\1',s)
```

But it seems that it is not the right call as **"Populated places established in 1624"** also deleted the " from 1624 which I don't want to happen.

How can I overcome this problem?

The desired result should be:

```
s = """[{"id" : 645042,"begin": 33,"end": 46,"entity": "New York City","text": "New York City","score": 0.40,"categories" : ["New York City","Cities in New York","Former capitals of the United States","Former United States state capitals","Government of New York City","Metropolitan areas of New York","Populated places established in 1624","Populated places on the Hudson River","Port cities and towns of the United States Atlantic coast","1624 establishments in the Thirteen Colonies","Article Feedback 5 Additional Articles"]}]"""
```

Any help for this will be much appreciated.

Comment: and does this id sometimes have it and other times it does not? Are we only looking for the value of `id`? Or can this happen in other id's.

Comment: Actually, there are many pattern of {...} in the [..] and each {..} contains at least one key id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you will be replacing all the number in the string which only have a closing quote (missing opening one).

In that case you can use the following pattern matching.

```py
re.sub(r'(:[\s]?[0-9]+)\"', '\\1' , s)
```

This pattern will actually look for all the numbers preceding with a colon (:) and may or may not contain a single space in between.

For the string mentioned by you, the above code gives output as follows.

```py
'[{"id" : 645042,"begin": 33,"end": 46,"entity": "New York City","text": "New York City","score": 0.40,"categories" : ["New York City","Cities in New York","Former capitals of the United States","Former United States state capitals","Government of New York City","Metropolitan areas of New York","Populated places established in 1624","Populated places on the Hudson River","Port cities and towns of the United States Atlantic coast","1624 establishments in the Thirteen Colonies","Article Feedback 5 Additional Articles"]}]'
```